dbatools & managed Service accounts
Ok, new to dbatools, am trying to use Install-DbaInstance using configuration in my powershell script.
eg (snippet):
$installParams = @{
    SQLInstance = $sqlServer
    Version = $SQLVersion
    Feature = $features
    DataPath = "D:\MSSQLDBs"
    LogPath = "E:\MSSQLLogs"
    TempPath = "F:\MSSQLTemp"
    BackupPath = "\\xxxxxx\mssqlbackups$"
    Path = $path
    Credential = $cred
}

Install-DbaInstance @installParams

When I specify EngineCredential - it won't accept my gmsa - it just sees it as an ordinary credential and requests a password.
So my question is how to I specify a gmsa account for my engine services?
Ian

You could try installing SQL using the default (virtual) service accounts and afterwards change the service account using Update-DbaServiceAccount. If I recall correctly, this is the workaround I used years ago with an older version of dbatools; not sure if this method is still needed in the latest version.
